# CSS split border colours

Tags: html, css, styles

I'm having trouble figuring out how to apply a split border on an element using CSS.

The effect I'm trying to achieve is this:

[image]

Where the red line and the grey line take up a % of the elements width. Preferably, I would like to apply this effect to an element using a single class.

**Edit:** for those asking for a code sample:

```
<!-- spans width 100% -->
<div id="wrapper">
    <h1 class="title">DDOS Protection </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us your code, HTML / CSS

Comment: Can't you just put them in separate containers (ie spans) with their own border? That should get you the desired effect. You can even add an overall container to prevent word-break and position them together. I don't think a split border is even possible.

Answer (score 3):

Red text and a red underline?  There's some simple CSS for this.

```
<span style='color:red; border-bottom: 1px solid red;'>DDOS</span>
<span style='color:#999; border-bottom: 1px solid #999;'>Protection</span>
```

Comment: Why recommend inline styles?

Comment: or connect it to a class in a stylesheet rather then inline CSS

Comment: This is just an example, I'm not saying inline styles are better than anything else.  Just showing how to achieve the effect he wants.

Comment: The inline styles makes the code sample harder to read since you're forced to scroll.

Comment: ok, I've multi-lined it. Hope that makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming that you want to use a single class, and without seeing your exact markup, this will work:

```
<div class="message">
    <span>DDOS</span>
    <span>Protection</span>
</div>
```

And then your CSS could look like this:

```
.message span {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    color: #ccc;
}
    .message span:first-child {
        border-bottom-color: red;
        color: red;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
```

Here's a [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/H8CSR/1/).

Comment: That's pretty close. What would I need to change if I wanted the bottom border of the second word to span the rest of the container?

Comment: Just add `display: block; float: left` to the spans, and then specify a width for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to play with `:before` and `:after`:

```
.line {
    background-color: #DDD;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.line:before, .line:after {
    content: '';
    width: 10%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.line:after {
    width: 90%;
    background-color: green;
    left: 10%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DHDuw/

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've made a similar one but that was asked for vertical, but now am changing the gradient direction so that it will help you

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/guvdU/1/) (Works On **Chrome**, If Anyone Knows Cross-Browser, Please Feel Free To Edit, Because Am Using Old Browsers So Won't Be Able To Test)

CSS

```
div {
  font: 40px Arial;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#ff0505), color-stop(50%,#ff0000), color-stop(50%,#000000), color-stop(100%,#000000));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: @Sinmok Did you used latest chrome?

Comment: Yeah. The D in the last word is a different colour but that's about it.

Comment: @Sinmok Have a look, seriously you feel this is wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/guvdU/3/ and here's the preview http://imgur.com/QhuLTU8

Comment: For cross-browser gradients, have a look here: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: @Pieter Not for cross browser gradients, it was for clip and fill colors but than too that helps partially ;) thought I can change the prefizes I cannot test them

Comment: @Mr.Alien Yeah, just updated to Chrome 25 and it's still buggered.

Comment: @Sinmok You can see the preview, it's perfect for me, if you want corss browser than simply use two spans, that's the best you can do

Comment: please let me know the reason for -1